# Implement “Edit Multiple Individually” for a model that `belongs_to` another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

I understand how [Railscast #198 “Edit Multiple Individually”](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually?view=asciicast) works for simply `/products`.

But if I had `/products/examples`, where `Examples` `belongs_to Product`, what would I have to edit/add?

Conceptually, I continue to have a hard time grasping this.  What knowledge holes do you recommend me filling?